# No file gxperf.gxd generated with Code Coverage

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to analyze the performance of some objects, so I activated the 'generate code coverage information' property and performed a rebuild. When I run the aplication, the **profiled file is not being generated**.

I expect to view the result in the profile file, but I currently see the file **empty**.

I work with Genexus 17 U7 in a java environment.